# Calculate difference between two time fields in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to calculate difference between two time fields in a view (mysql). I'm using this query:

```
$result = mysql_query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW arbtim AS SELECT week, name, start, stop, arton,
      ( arton ) - ( start ) AS t18 FROM arbtid;");
```

The field "arton" is always "18:00:00". If start = "10:00:00" it returns "80000". 
If start = "09:45:00" it returns "85500". 
I want it to be "8" and 8,25

Both fields are in time format. The created field t18 is in the double format - why?

Comment: Does the second one really return `85500`, not `81500`?

Comment: Or 82500 (which would be really convenient).

Comment: Yes its 85500... buhu ;(

Comment: Thank to you all, now im back on track. I was realy stuck

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html), unfortunately 85500 is the documented behaviour. I know what you are thinking... that sucks :(

The problem is that TIME is converted to 10000 * hours + 100 * minutes + seconds.

Since you want hours, I suggest you do it explicitly:

```
(3600*HOUR(arton)+60*MINUTE(arton)+SECOND(arton)
-3600*HOUR(start)-60*MINUTE(start)-SECOND(start))/3600 AS t18
```

which (thanks to GolezTrol), with the TIME_TO_SEC function, can be more simply written as:

```
(TIME_TO_SEC(arton)-TIME_TO_SEC(start))/3600 AS t18
```

---

But I want to go deeper with this answer, because this strange TIME algebra bothers me a lot. I've never seen something like this in any other RDBMS or language. Mind you, I haven't seen them all, but quite a few.

**What bothers me is that this TIME algebra is a trap, especially for the inexperienced.**

There are just too many things that can go wrong with this. Here's a partial list:

- 100 is 00:01:00, but 100-1 is not 00:00:59, but an invalid time
- 100 is 00:01:00, but 100*100 is not 01:40:00, but 01:00:00
- 100 is 00:01:00, but 100/2 is not 00:00:30, but 00:00:50

... and many others I might add as I think of them.

***Do you see where I am getting? Do not operate on time columns... not in this warped and incomplete space MySQL provides us. In this space most operations will not work as we would expect them to.***

The only reasonable solution here is to get out... convert those times to something else we can sum, subtract, divide and multiply as we would expect. TIME_TO_SEC is a good simple choice, but there are others. And do convert TIME values **before** doing anything else with them.

Comment: yippie cay a (sorry for my english...) you made my day. (or actoally my week). Cheers. Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of correct ways of doing it:

Using timestamps - in this case, the result will be in seconds:

```
SELECT week, name, start, stop, arton,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP( arton ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( start ) AS t18 FROM arbtid;
```

Then, to get hours, divide the number of seconds by 3,600.

Or using `TIMEDIFF` - in this case, the result will be a time value like "-00:00:00.000001":

```
SELECT week, name, start, stop, arton,  TIMEDIFF( arton, start ) AS t18 FROM arbtid;
```

I think the former is probably more suitable for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TIME_TO_SEC` to get the number of seconds in the time span. 
Then, you can use that to calculate the hours, by simply dividing it by 3600.

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(arton - start) / 3600 AS HoursBetween FROM arbtid
```

Comment: Beware... this is subtly wrong. With this strange TIME algebra, you cannot afford to subtract **before** converting. You will get strange results. But thanks for the TIME_TO_SEC... I didn't know that one.